# libGDX: game universal speed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am new to libGDX,
i'm trying to make a feature in my game where the player clicks on a button and the whole game speed is increased by a factor of 2.
i dont want to change every game element's speed, i'm looking for a global option of controlling the 'game tick' speed.

Comment: Do you mean changing the game's speed from 30 fps to 60 fps, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to conserve a proper frame independant application (game) you must use the time passed between two frames. Libgdx already gives you this in the render method of your screens if you use [Game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.java) in the form a a float argument called **delta** or **deltaTime**. If you don't, you can still use [Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getDeltaTime--) to get it.

If you already do this (you should!). Just multiply it for 2 before the game updates.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta){
    delta = delta * 2;
    //game logic
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this tick timer for doing world updates. It tells the world to update it's state every 50 milliseconds, 20 times a second.

The render method gets called every time for updating unimportant things like particle effects that don't need a world update and the world in its current state and npc entities moving at their given speed.

To increase game speed just modify the game tick treshold `ticktime` to a lower number. But as Gdx will most likely run 60fps setting it lower than 16 won't have an effect.

```
// time elapsed in the world in milliseconds
public long time = 0l;
// how long to wait between ticks, in milliseconds
public long ticktime = 50l;
// when did we last send a tick?
public long lastTick=0l;

   @Override
   public void render()
    {        
    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    // convert to milliseconds
    time+=(long)(delta*1000);
    // Simple substraction to see if enough time passed for a world update
    if(time - ticktime > lastTick) {
        GameWorld.tick();
        long elapsed = time - lastTick;
        if(elapsed > ticktime) {
            long missed = elapsed / ticktime;
            if(missed > 3l) {
               System.err.println("Warning: skipping "+missed+" ticks");
            }
        }
        lastTick = time - (time % ticktime);
    }
    WorlRenderer.render(delta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Lestat for multiplying delta by 2 (or any needed factor). Just wanted to add a suggestion to distinct code that calculates (object positions, collisions and stuff) from the code that draws the graphics. And when you calculate delta then, based on it's value also calculate how many times your calculation code should be executed, and execute it that many times. And do the drawing after that, just once.
Point is, that if you speed up your time (or you have slow FPS on some devices) you can miss some important time frames. I.e. you have some bullet traveling 5px per frame. And you speed up your time (or frame rate drops) difference between 2 frames (and 2 calculations) can be too big and if you only multiply bullet speed with that delta parameter you movement step can be too big, so your bullet can avoid some (hit) detection and i.e. pass trough the enemy without hitting it. So main idea is to repeat calculation in smaller steps ("game clock") and not miss the action and draw in as more as possible.